# What does the following translate to in english? "Jawooooolllllooo! - feeling hot -boy-mäßig"

Tags: german-to-english, slang, teen-slang

I saw this on twitter, posted by a german female friend of mine but have no idea what it means, especially the Jawooolllooo part. Google translates mäßig as "Moderately". Could anyone tell me what is meant by the entire phrase please? Thanks

Comment: Why you don't ask your friend. The ending "[-mäßig](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-mäßig)" is "[-like](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_7)". It's not slang.

Comment: @Baz Why do you think so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Jawooolllooo" is the extended version of "Jawohl". It's like writing "YYYYEEEEESSSSS".

Google was right with "mäßig" if the word stood alone. But here it is used as a suffix and has a different meaning. You can translate "hot-boy-mäßig" with "like a hot-boy".